# Let users manage certain field

Tags: 7, users

I'd like to give a set of users the ability to manage certain fields, such as adding items to a list. Is this in any way possible with existing modules?

Example:
Editing a node
Try to select XYZ for field FOO
XYZ isn't an option
Go to admin page and add XYZ to FOO
Can now select XYZ from FOO

Answer (score 0):

I think the module [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions/) allows you to do what you're looking for. Or at least in the documentation it write "Create own value for the field".

Comment: That doesn't do what I need. I tried that one and while neat, doesn't address my issue.